# Regex expression not following the given length

Tags: regex

I have the regex as follow:

`^[a-z|A-Z]((?!.*--).*[[:alnum:]]|[-]){1,22}[a-z|A-Z|0-9]$`

For some reason, the length of the given string if set to 24+ is still accepted. The original capture group needs to be: string between 3-24 alphanumeric characters, must begin with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and cannot contain consecutive hyphens.

Why is the regex not checking the quantifier of length 1-22 in the middle part?

Comment: You have `.*` in the pattern that's repeated 1-22 times. So the matched string can be longer than 22.

Comment: Why do you have two `|` in the `[a-z|A-Z|0-9]` character set? Do you even want to match the `|` character there? It's not an alternative separator inside `[]`, it's a literal character.

Comment: Its either A-Z or a-z or 0-9.

Comment: That would be `[a-zA-Z0-9]` you don't need `|`.

Comment: You say 3-24 alphanumeric characters. So how does that allow any hyphens? They're not alphanumeric.

Comment: Alphanumeric usually just means letters and digits, but I can imagine contexts where the "numeric" part means anything that can be in a number, which includes `-` for negative numbers, `+` for positive, and maybe even decimal points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main pattern should be just `^[a-z].{1,22}[a-z\d]$` to specify that the whole match must be 3-24 characters and have the required beginning and ending characters. You can use the case-insensitive modifier to make `a-z` match `A-Z` as well.

Then add a negative lookahead to prohibit `.*--`. The final result is:

```
^(?!.*--)[a-z].{1,22}[a-z\d]$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MN4HPV/1)